# How to get the current Pane ID a module is placed on in DNN?

Tags: dotnetnuke, dnn9

How could you retrieve the unique ID of the Pane a DNN module is placed on?

I found this article but it is using Razor and only the ModuleID is being retrieved. I need the Pane ID that is containing the module:
https://www.dnnsoftware.com/forums/threadid/499025/scope/posts/get-the-id-of-a-module-instance-or-the-name-of-the-pane-containing-the-module

Comment: Can you pass the PaneID to the template in your Razor code? It should be available there.

Comment: @Mickers - I am not using Razor. Just the normal view.ascx files from a DNN Christoc Template

Answer (score 1):

If you have the ModuleId, you can find the PaneName in the TabModules table.  There is a method named TabModulesController in DotNetNuke.Entities.Tabs.  That should give you a starting point.